# Submitting objects and lists struts1

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-1

I have a class `MyClass` as below

```
public class MyClass {
    private int fieldOne;        //with getter, setter
    private String fieldTwo;     //with getter, setter
}
```

I have following two fields in my form bean

```
private MyClass myObject;            //with getter, setter
private ArraList<MyClass>myList;     //with getter, setter
```

Using struts1 I want to submit object and list of objects from web-page form.

In struts2 we can get object and list in action as below (considering fields are not in action class instead of form bean). When following fields are submitted, struts2 initiates `myObject` and `myList` for me with submitted values. (Parameters Interceptor is the magician behind the scene in struts2.)

```
<!-- Object -->
<input type="text" name="myObject.fieldOne" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="myObject.fieldTwo" value="Two" />
...
<!-- List -->
<input type="text" name="myList[0].fieldOne" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="myList[0].fieldTwo" value="Two" />

<input type="text" name="myList[1].fieldOne" value="10" />
<input type="text" name="myList[1].fieldTwo" value="Twenty" />
```

Is there any way to perform such magic in struts1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIR, the same would work in Struts1, provided the list in your form bean contains a list which already has the right size. I.e. if the last input text has the name `myList[7].fieldOne`, the list should be of size 8 at least, and thus be prepopulated with 8 `MyClass` instances. STruts will only do `formBean.getMyList().get(7).setFieldOne(10)`.

See http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/indexedprops.html for more details.